# GRASS tools on QGIS unable to open data source from Onedrive

Tags: qgis-grass-plugin, onedrive

Every time I run GRASS tools on QGIS, where the data source is located on Onedrive folders, I always receive this error "ERROR: Unable to open data source <C:\Users....>". When I move the file to a local drive, it works normally. However, it's too much trouble since I have to copy-paste the file back and forth. There is no problem when using other tools with files from Onedrive.

Is there anything I can do to make GRASS reads the data source files from Onedrive properly? I'm working with QGIS 3.22.3 on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried to run the QGIS with GRASS program as an administrator?

Comment: I just tried to run QGIS as administrator, now even the plugins are unavailable to download and do not allow me to make any connections. I think it has something to do with the company administrator. Running it normally is better.